# emberjs foundation 5 accordion

Tags: javascript, ember.js, accordion, zurb-foundation

i am new to emberjs, and have the following template with some fields in it, which is fixed and should match some fields in a model, but when i use foundation accordion with ember js, it shows up fine, but when i click it, it does not "unfold".

how to get emberjs and foundation accordion to work together? it seems the click on the href gets send to the hashtag of the url

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="entries">
    <div class="row ">
        <dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
            <dd>
                <a href="#panel1">Accordion 1</a>
                <div id="panel1" class="content">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    {{input type="text" value=name}}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-6 columns">
                            <label>Addresse</label>
                            {{input type="text" value=adress}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you added foundation to the page? Do you call foundation() on the dom object after you have attached it?

Comment: Do you have an example? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Why are you not using the {{link-to}} helper?

Comment: @Hrishi : Because he is not trying to link to any resource. That `<a>` tag is used for the triggering accordion.

Answer (score 0):

You should call foundation() after the view has been inserted. For example, if this template is for an `entry` resource, you should do something like the following in your `EntryView`'s `didInsertElement`:

**CoffeeScript:**

```
EntryView = Ember.View.extend
  didInsertElement: ->
    @$().foundation()
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var EntryView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().foundation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by re-implementing some of Foundation's behavior. Foundation hides and shows the accordion sections by adding and removing the `active` class on the element with the `content` class.

```
<div class="row ">
    <dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
        <dd>
            <a href="#panel1">Accordion 1</a>
            <div id="panel1" class="content">
                <!-- Closed panel -->
            </div>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <a href="#panel2">Accordion 2</a>
            <div id="panel2" class="content active">
                <!-- Open panel -->
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

You can simulate this in your browser dev tools easily enough, but you can also bind it to an Ember action like this:

**//my_view.js**

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  actions: {
    toggle: function(selector) {
      this.$(selector).toggleClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

**//template.hbs**

```
<dd>
  <a {{action "toggle" "#panel1" target="view">Accordion 1</a>
  <div id="panel1" class="content">
    <!-- Closed panel -->
  </div>
</dd>
```

The magic is in the `action` helper, which triggers the functionality in the `toggle` action  defined in the view. You pass the content div's ID as the selector to the toggle function, which then has its `active` class turned on or off by jQuery.

Something to note is the `target="view"` which tells Ember to use the `action` on the View, rather than going to the Ember `Route` you're under. If this looks messy to you, you could put the `toggle` action on your `Route` class, but it feels more like view functionality to me.